# When inheriting from ModuleType how can I get type hints to show in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I create a module by inheriting from `ModuleType` because it provides more control on how the module is used. For example you can provide read-only properties and create dynamic properties.

```
from types import ModuleType

class Module(ModuleType):
    def __init__(self, name: str, doc):
        super().__init__(name, doc)
        self.prop: str = 'test'

sys.modules[__name__] = Module(__name__, Module.__doc__)
```

How can I have type hints of `Module` to appear in PyCharm?

Comment: PyCharm knows what `import` statements do. It doesn't necessarily know what assigning to `sys.modules` means. There is a lot of stuff that editors treat as static information only because they are special-cased to do so, not because the information is inherently static.

Comment: There definitely is a way to do it. I have checked and get_type_hints returns the exepected types.

Comment: You say you want type hints but where at? In another file when you want to use `Module`? Also `get_type_hints` is a runtime function. Mean ofc it will return the type hints but does that mean pycharm should assume that, that module is loaded and start giving random hints? `sys.modules` is global and could be loaded with a bunch of stuff. Pycharm cant know whats loaded unless it runs the code and does "reflection" on it. And sometimes stuff isnt imported until certain code is called so then pycharm would have to know how to navigate your whole app to import it and then "reflect" it

Comment: Yes in another file. What does pycharm use to get the annotations of a module? I have tried setting __annotations__ on the module level but no luck.

Comment: _A static type checker does not execute your code, it just reads it._ As the other guys said, just because _you_ know what type something is at runtime, does not mean any type checker does after parsing your code. Aside from that, what you are doing is so far from type safe that I would not expect any type checker/IDE to recognize it.

Comment: Yeh I would agree with you that this isn't possible. But I have seen a solution for this somewhere on the internet and I used that solution at my previous place of work. It definitely possible.

Comment: A type-safe approximation is possible through the use of `.pyi` stub files. Implement an `ast.NodeVisitor` call in Python 3.9+ to dynamically write `.pyi` stub files when you call `__init_subclass__` on your `Module`.